# Restrict access for publishing API to publisher only

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Was following the WSO2 course and landed on this. So far, only the admin account can publish and API. I just want the API creator to create the API and the API publisher to publish it.

I tried to create different roles and give them only the permissions they required like creator > creates and publisher > publishes. That has not worked so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create roles from the management console and do the relevant role mappings from the Admin Portal. For example, if you want a user who can do CRUD operations on an API, you can assign a role which has `Internal/creator` mapping to that user. Or if you need more fine grained permissions, you can assign the relevant scopes in the Role Permissions section in the Admin Portal.

Please refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/managing-users-and-roles/managing-user-roles/#creating-user-roles for more information. This also explains what are specific permissions (scopes) applied to each of creator, publisher, etc. You can use that to get an idea of each role's capabilities.